# RegExp pattern to capture around two-characters delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a string which is something like:

```
prefix::key0==value0::key1==value1::key2==value2::key3==value3::key4==value4::
```

I want to retrieve the value associated to a key (say, key1). The following pattern:

```
::key1==([^:]*)
```

...will work only if there are no '`:`' character in the value, so I want to make sure the pattern matching will stop only for the substring `::`, but I'm can't find how to do that, as most examples I see are about single character matching.

How do I modify the regexp pattern to match all characters between "`::key1==`" and the next "`::`" ?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure what language you are using, but for example w/ php, any reason you can't just explode() using '::' as the delimiter instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like this : `::key1==(.*?)::`? Assuming the language supports the lazy `?` operator, this should work.

Comment: This should indeed work if `?` is supported.

You can always use http://www.regexpal.com for testing regex matching capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a positive look-ahead:

```
::key0==(.*?)(?=::\w+==)
```

With the following:

```
prefix::key0==val::ue0::key1==value1::key2==value2::key3==value3::key4==value4::
```

It correctly finds **val::ue0**. This also assumes the keys conform to **\w** ([0-9A-Za-z_])

*Also, a positive look-ahead may be a bit of overkill, but will work if the answer contains `::`, too.*

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment to your question, if the entirety of your string is

```
prefix::key0==value0::key1==value1::key2==value2::key3==value3::key4==value4::
```

I would suggest exploding/splitting the string at :: instead of using regex as it will usually always be faster.  You didn't specify language but here is a php example:

```
// string
$string = "prefix::key0==value0::key1==value1::key2==value2::key3==value3::key4==value4::";
// explode using :: as delimiter
$string = explode('::',$string);
// for each element...
foreach ($string as $value) {
  // check if it has == in it 
  if (strpos($value,'==')!==false) $matches[] = $value;
}
// output
echo "<pre>";print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => key0==value0
    [1] => key1==value1
    [2] => key2==value2
    [3] => key3==value3
    [4] => key4==value4
)
```

However, if you insist on the regex approach, here negative look-ahead alternative

```
::((?:(?!::).)+)
```

php example

```
// string
$string = "prefix::key0==value0::key1==value1::key2==value2::key3==value3::key4==value4::";
preg_match_all('~::((?:(?!::).)+)~',$string,$matches);
//output
echo "<pre>";print_r($matches);
```

output

```
Array
    (
        [0] => key0==value0
        [1] => key1==value1
        [2] => key2==value2
        [3] => key3==value3
        [4] => key4==value4
    )
```